# Widget to show that function is 'running' in published Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

In a published Jupyter notebook is there a way to insert a widget that says "running" or something similar when I am running a function.

I am aware of the tqdm function but to the best of my knowledge this is only when the function / process contains a for-loop.

I currently have a series of dropdown widgets with a submit button but some of the functions take a while for the calcs to run so i have no way of telling if the're running or not

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I have done this in the past is to have a function as a context manager, that displays some value to a Text widget to indicate that the function is running. You could also use an Output widget to display a indeterminate 'progress' bar like the one below:

https://www.iselect.com.au/content/themes/iselect/images/post/loader.gif

```py
import ipywidgets as ipyw
import time
from contextlib import contextmanager

label = ipyw.Text('Ready')
button = ipyw.Button(description='Click me')

@contextmanager
def show_loading():
    label.value = 'Running...'
    yield
    label.value = 'Ready'

def long_running_function(self):
    with show_loading():
        time.sleep(2)
        
button.on_click(long_running_function)

display(button)    
display(label)
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps. I am doing some OpenCV thing, thresholding based on rgb values using some sliders. My code runs slower when using python widgets, but was working faster when using OpenCV's trackbar. Is there a lot of overhead in using widgets?

Comment: Hi, can you show your two versions in a new question? Are you using the ipywidgets progress bar widget? I would suggest line profiling your code to determine for sure: see here for an example https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.07-timing-and-profiling.html#Line-By-Line-Profiling-with-%lprun